# Retry failed step in Selenium IDE

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-ide

Is there a way to configure the Selenium IDE to retry a failed step after a defined period of time (e.g. 1 second)?

This way you could let the tests run at the fastest speed, even with dynamic elements, without having to check each element separately.

Comment: i feel like the answer is NO. For that you would need webdriver approach with some implicit waiting...

Comment: I'd also agree with the above, you are starting to stretch the IDE to it's limits, and it's at this point you should be thinking about diving into actual programming code. The various WebDriver API's have a lot of ready-made code for you to use to make this simple, but it's way outside the IDE's scope.

Comment: Nah you can't Selenium IDE is only supposed to be used as a beginning point, not for real automation. You will have many such issues going with IDE. As above commentator mentioned, go with WebDriver if you really want effective automation.

Comment: How can webdriver(java) be used to achieve the same? I only find retry FAILED TESTS and could not find a way to implement retry FAILED STEP using some retry method!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. research, download, and apply the sideflow extension to selenium IDE. It adds several conditional commands to IDE including a while loop. The IDE commands would then look something like this:

```
store  |  <target>  |  <variable>
while  | <target> != desired_value  | 
pause  |  1000  |
store  |  <target>  |  <variable>
endWhile
```

This solution will try your while condition every 1000 milliseconds (1 second) forever. With a little creativity you can also tell it to fail after x seconds.
Hope this helps.